# Tryton show message 403 forbidden error durin installation of GNUhealth in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnu, tryton

[As you can see the error 403 forbidden error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jbTw.jpg)I have installed ubuntu 20.04 in VM virtual box. I need to install GNU Health on ubuntu. I have followed this article on Wikibooks.
Here is the link to an article (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation#Installing_GNU_Health_on_GNU/Linux_and_FreeBSD).
Everything was fine i installed all dependencies correctly and when I reached to GNU installation step following this command
(bash ./gnuhealth-setup install).
GNU is installed successfully but when it comes to installing the Tryton package it shows the error message (403..Forbidden Message) when i open the Tryton website it was fine but its link not working in the Terminal.

I have tried to follow this video on youtube but it is not working.
https://youtu.be/ivGwM9y6YOk

Answer (score 1):

Tryton by default does not include the web client as you can use the Desktop client to connect to the server.

When the web client is not installed the server returns a forbidden error when accessed via web browser.

The tryton web client is called sao. Make sure to read the [installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryton-sao) notes. [Here](https://discuss.tryton.org/t/instal-sao-for-gnuhealth-on-ubuntu-20-04/4370) is a tutorial to install it on gnuhealth. Please note that the sao version must match the same server version.

You can now your trytond version using the following command:

```
$ trytond --version
trytond 6.0.14
```

You should just use the first two digits of the server version to match the sao version. So following my example you should use the sao version 6.0.x to connect on the server.

Comment: After this command (bash ./gnuhealth-setup install) it was getting GNU Health and completed it successfully but when it moves to Tryton and try to get tryton it gives the error.The error is 403 forbidden error.

Comment: The problem is that the gnuhealth iinstall script does not install the web client so you must install it manually. That's what I explained in the above reply.

Comment: i want to install trytond server? when i install gnu health by this command (bash ./gnuhealth-setup install) it is installing perfect and when it reaches to collecting trytond then it gives the error 403 forbidden error.

Comment: You already have the server running. You can connect on it using the standard tryton client (or even the gnuhealth client). To be able to connect from we you need the web client as I already explained